# Changing the label of an Android Activity?

Tags: android

Im trying to change the label of an android activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
```

The above is valid, but when I change it to something like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_test">
```

It doesnt work, I get the error:

```
Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is there any string with title_activity_main_test in strings.xml exists in string folder in resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of (title_activity_main_test) shuld be declared in the strings.xml file in res/values..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The attribute values "@string/title_activity_main" and "@string/title_activity_main_test" are references to resources used by your Android application.

The first part - @string, refers to the file res\values\strings.xml in your Android project. (If you wanted to refer to an image, for example, then the first part of the value would start with "@drawable".)

The strings.xml file is supposed to contain all the user-facing strings that you want to use in your application. If you are adding a new string, then you need a new element in that file. If you want to just change the value of an existing string, don't change its name. Just change its value.